# Related To Web-Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-services

How to call REST web service URL of POST method using javascript or ajax or jquery?
 Can I can Sample code Please or Any Site Which has the code 
          And In advance Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using jquery. This basic syntax is explained on their site. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/