# Calling a RESTFUL web service with POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related To Web-Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857839/related-to-web-service)

How to call RESTFUL web service URL with POST method using JavaScript or ajax or jQuery?

Can I get sample code for this or could you suggest a good site with an example?

Answer (score 3):

Other than jQuery.post as suggested, you can also use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the type attribute set as 'POST', for instance:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/service/url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'extraparam=45869159&another=32',
    success: function (data) {
        //handle the returned data
    }
});
```

The type attribute works with `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Despite the following *Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.*

I haven't found a browser yet that doesn't support them. Also IE 6 does support them.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ it's well documented and there are a lots of examples, as well as comments and tips from other users.